# Replace chartjs data

Tags: javascript, chart.js

How can i replace `myChart["data"]` in a ChartJS instance?

I receive two sets of data from my backend. I can swap out individual data-points with `myChart["data"]["datasets"][0]["data"] = [1,2,3];` but not the whole data object. Why is that?

The following code does not work (see the "THIS DOES NOT WORK" comment in the code).

HTML:

```
<div class="col s12 m6 l8">
    <span id="control1">UMSCHALTER</span>
    <canvas id="kontakteChart" width="600" height="300"></canvas>
</div> <!-- col -->
```

IMPORTS/VERSION:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.bundle.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

JS:

```
// Supplied Datasets to display
var data1 = {"labels": ["1", "2", "3"], "datasets": [{"label": "Contacts", "data": [20, 15, 10], "backgroundColor": "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)", "borderColor": "rgba(255,99,132,1)", "borderWidth": 1}]};
var data2 = {"labels": ["1", "2", "3"], "datasets": [{"label": "Contacts", "data": [10, 23, 41], "backgroundColor": "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)", "borderColor": "rgba(255,99,132,1)", "borderWidth": 1}]};

// Draw the initial chart
var kChartCanvas = $("#kontakteChart");
var myChart = new Chart(kChartCanvas, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data1,

    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});

// Called on Click
function chartContent(){
    console.log(myChart["data"]);
    myChart["data"] = data2; // <<<<------ THIS DOES NOT WORK.
    myChart.update();
}

// Set the listener for the click function
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#control1" ).click(chartContent); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set **`myChart["config"]["data"] = data2`** instead

```js
// Supplied Datasets to display
var data1 = { "labels": ["1", "2", "3"], "datasets": [{ "label": "Contacts", "data": [20, 15, 10], "backgroundColor": "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)", "borderColor": "rgba(255,99,132,1)", "borderWidth": 1 }] };
var data2 = { "labels": ["1", "2", "3"], "datasets": [{ "label": "Contacts", "data": [10, 23, 41], "backgroundColor": "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)", "borderColor": "rgba(255,99,132,1)", "borderWidth": 1 }] };

// Draw the initial chart
var kChartCanvas = $("#kontakteChart")[0].getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(kChartCanvas, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data1,
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});

// Called on Click
function chartContent() {
    myChart["config"]["data"] = data2; //<--- THIS WORKS!
    myChart.update();
}

// Set the listener for the click function
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#control1").click(chartContent);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="kontakteChart"></canvas>
<button id="control1">UMSCHALTER</button>
```

Comment: Hi @GRUNT do you know why replacing data object with its clone can cause an error?
`function chartContent() {
    myChart["config"]["data"] = _.cloneDeep(myChart["config"]["data"]);
    myChart.update();
}` Thank you for any hint.